# Custom built PC no video and no beep

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, post

I have this built PC since 2014, but i didn't use it at all since 2017 because I've moved to another city and couldn't bring it with me.  Lately I've been trying to power it up to no avail, it powers up, the fans run but no image is shown and no POST beep can be heard.

Motherboard: [Asus B85M-E](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/B85M-E/E9915_B85M-E_Manual_v3_web.pdf)
Processor: Intel i7-4790k
Memory: Corsair Vengeance Pro Series (2x8GB)
Main Drive: HDD Seagate 2000gb ST2000DM001
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760
PSU: Corsair CX750M

When I remove the memory, I get one long and two short beeps, repeating. According to the manual, the memory isn't detected, which, well, it's correct.

But when I plug in the memory, I get no image and no POST beep, I tried moving the memory and cleaning with a eraser, I also removed one of the memory sticks and tested both, but nothing fixes it.

I tried switching the video card slots and even removing the video card and test the on board card, but nothing.

I cleared the CMOS and did many of the steps I've found on the internet, including reseating everything, even the processor, nothing.

I also tested multiple monitors.

Do someone have a clue what it could be?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right video output? As in, is your HDMI/DP/DVI plugged into the graphics card or motherboard?

Comment: ASUS Troubleshooting links: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/B85ME/HelpDesk/

Comment: Of course, as i've said, i've tested both the graphic cards and onboard graphics.

I'm also aware of the troubleshooting link, as i've said, i've did many steps and nothing seemed to work, which is why i asked if someone had a similar problema and managed to fix it.